# Finding the equation of a plane

Tags: plane-geometry

**Three planes have the equation**
$$ \pi_1:x+2y-3z=-4$$
$$ \pi_2:2x+y-4z=3$$
$$ \pi_3:x+2y-3z+4+\lambda(2x+y-4z-3)=0$$

**Find the equation of the plane $\pi_3$ which passes through the line on which $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ meet and contains the point whose position vector is $\alpha k$**

I first calculated the vector equation of the line on which the two planes meet. Using the position vector of the line and the $\alpha k$, I calculated a vector that $\pi_3$ contains. Cross product of line direction vector and obtained vector gives the normal to the plane. The dot product of the normal and the $\alpha k$ position vector completes the equation of the plane.

I obtained 
$$-(2\alpha +5)x+(5\alpha +2)y+7z=7a$$

The given answer is 
$$(-2\alpha +11)x+(5\alpha +10)y-25z=-25a$$

Can somebody please check if these answers are same? If no, then maybe explain the flaw in my strategy?

P.S. I am aware of the second method that involves directly putting the position vector in the $\pi_3$ plane.

**Working**

Line equation:$2/3 i +5/3 j+(5i+2j+3k)t$

Normal Obtained: $(5,2,3)\times(2/3,5/3,-\alpha)=-(2\alpha +5)i+(5\alpha +2)j+7k$

Dot product of normal and position vector :$7a$

If some answers seems doubtful, upon request, I will provide detailed working.

Comment: The “correct” answer that you’ve given here doesn’t look right. I get $-25\alpha$ after substituting into the given equation for $\pi_3$.

Comment: You appear to have made a mistake in calculating $\pi_1\cap\pi_2$. No point of the line that you claim is this intersection lies in $\pi_1$.

Comment: Yes got it thanks